# Are there other terms for "multi-armed bandit experiments"?

Tags: econometrics, experiment-design, epidemiology, multiarmed-bandit

In a multi-armed bandit experiment, many treatments (or actions) are compared, and we aim to discover the best treatments in a short time ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit), [google analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2844870?hl=en))

Do other fields (maybe economics or epidemiology) have terms for similar kinds of experiments?

Comment: Sequential design I think has similar aims https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_analysis

Comment: Multi armed bandit could be thought of as a part of reinforcement learning, adaptive sequential learning and a lot of these come under statistical learning theory. I think in economics people use MAB's for dynamic online pricing etc. but I am not aware of a separate name/term used for these.